# How can I translate ONLY the labels of picklists in my visual flow?

Tags: picklist, visual-workflow, flow

I have a Visual Workflow that is embedded in a Visualforce Page that picks out the user's language and renders accordingly. Now that It's possible to use labels in the flows, Salesforce's translation tools work even better than I expected -- with the glaring exception of picklists.

**The picklist value labels are translated appropriately, but the actual values are being translated as well**, so when I run a record update, **the record is not updated in my organization's master language** but in the user's language.

Is this how it is supposed to work? Has anyone else encountered this? And regardless, **how might I go about grabbing the corresponding option in the field definition**?

Thanks in advance! Any input would be greatly appreciated.